# Checkbox in a column Grid

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, webgrid

I have a Grid in Asp.net MVC 3, I want that in the column "Active?" displays a checkbox indicating if the user is active or not, now I get the word "true".

I want to change the word "true" for a check box that can not be changed, how i do this?

```
@grid.GetHtml(  fillEmptyRows: false,
                tableStyle : "table",
                mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
                columns: new [] {
                grid.Column("IdUser", header: "User"),
                grid.Column("Name", header: "Name"),
                grid.Column("Lastname", header: "Lastname"),
                grid.Column( "Active" ,header: "Active?")
        )
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use WebGrid.Column's **format** parameter for this.

```
grid.Column(
    header: "Active",
    format: (col) => @Html.Raw("<input type='checkbox' checked='" + ((col.Active) ? "checked" : "") + "' disabled='true' />")
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
grid.Column(
    "Active",
    format: item => @Html.CheckBox("Active", (bool)(item.Active ?? false), new { @disabled = "disabled" }), style: "center"
)
```

The 'style: "center"' may be omitted if you want :)

Good luck!